# How do you add a delimiter in a given String format in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String

```
"12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00";
```

I have to update the string to use the following format:

```
"12:00:00, 2:30:00 |3:45:00,23:45:00 ";
```

I am able to split each string, but I do not know how to generate the required format. Here is the code I've written so far:

```java
final String s = "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
final List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group(1));
}
for (String tok : tokens) {
    System.out.printf("[%s]%n", tok);
}
```

Comment: But `6:34:00,5:12:00` isn't there in input?

Comment: i mistakenly did that you can go with the input

Comment: @anubhava can you help???

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What exactly you want to add to your text? At first you are adding `_|` (where `_` is space) but then you are adding `_|_`. So which is it?

Comment: Also " make the String like..." doesn't explain everything. You need to be more precise. Do you want to add delimiter only after some specific dates? Or do you want to add it after each two dates separated by comma? Or maybe there is some other way you decide where this delimiter should be added?

Comment: @anubhava 12:00:00, 2:30:00|3:45:00,23:45:00|   this is

Comment: @Pshemo i want to add delimiter after each two  times like 12:00:00, 2:30:00|3:45:00,23:45:00| this

Comment: @anubhava am i clear now ??

Comment: So what is the problem? You already have list with your dates. Create `StringBuilder`, iterate over list by picking two dates, append them to builder and add `|`, move to next two elements.

Comment: @Pshemo can you edit my post i am not getting actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
final String string = "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
final List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    tokens.add(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println("tokens = " + tokens);

StringBuilder formattedString = new StringBuilder();
formattedString.append(tokens.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        formattedString.append(" | ");
    } else {
        formattedString.append(", ");
    }
    formattedString.append(tokens.get(i));
}
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Edit: I've updated it to use a for loop when constructing the formatted string based on the comments I've read.

Comment: i want the output in one String like the  number of parameters can be different in each cases....

Comment: @lucifer Ok I've updated the code. I think it will work the right way now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `|` after two dates separated by comma your code can look like

```
final String s = "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
String result = m.replaceAll("$0|");
```

Or even

```
String result = s.replaceAll("?:\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d),\\s*(?:\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)","$0|");
```

`$0` refers to group 0 which holds entire match.

`result` is `12:00:00, 2:30:00|3:45:00,23:45:00|`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this `replaceAll` method using lookarounds:

```
final String s = "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00";
System.out.printf("%s%n", s.replaceAll("(?<=:\\d\\d)(?=(?::\\d{1,2}|$))", "|"));

// 12:00|:00, 2:30|:003:45|:00,23:45|:00|
```